# Glassfish Admin Console stopped after change keystore.jks

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I use GF 3.1.2.2 and now I need to configure a Lets Encrypt SSL certificate for my webapp. After I changed the default keystore.jks with the new including the Lets Encrypt cert, my webapp worked fine, but Admin Console no.

The server.log file arises this error because it needs the default keytore.jks file:

[#|2016-05-17T11:31:15.344-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=72;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target;
restRequest: endpoint=https://localhost:4848/management/domain/anonymous-user-enabled
attrs={}
method=GET|#]

Answer (score 3):

I am 3 years late, but who knows maybe someone reads it anyway :)
The reason for your problem is that the certificate the admin-listener uses, is not within your new keystore.

The default certificate the admin-listener (Port 4848) uses has the Alias-Name 's1as' and is provided with the Glassfish installation.
This certificate is within the Default-Keystore keystore.jks.

If you changed the keystore with a new one, then Glassfish can't find the certificate he uses for the admin-listener.

This is most probably the solution to your problem:

**Easy one:**

- Stop glassfish
- Go to domain.xml in Path `./glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/config` and whereever you find an attribute with the name 'cert-nickname' change the value to the Alias-Name of your Let's Encrypt Certificate.
- Restart Glassfish

**Harder but more sophisticated:**

1. **Find out which certificate your admin-listener used before.**

   - For that temporarily change back to your old keystore.jks.
   - Login into the
     Admin console and go look for the Certificate NickName under
     `/Configurations/server-config/Http-Service/Http-Listeners/admin-listeners`.
     The default certificate Glassfish uses has the Name s1as.
2. a) If its a fresh Glassfish installation and the admin-listener still uses the default certificate s1as then i would suggest you switch over to your new Certificate.

   - Just change the Certificate NickName to the Alias-Name of your Lets' Encrypt certificate and click the save button.
   - Stop Glassfish
   - Switch over to your new Keystore
   - Start Glassfish

   b) If you insist on keeping the old certificate then you have to extract it from your 'old' keystore via keytool and import it into your new keystore.

   - Stop Glassfish
   - Extract the old certificate with this command:

     ```
      keytool -export -alias myOldCertificateNickname -keystore keystore.jks -file myOldCertificate.crt
     ```

     **Replace myOldCertificateNickname with the Certificate NickName you found in Step 1!**
   - Import your freshly exported old certificate into your new keystore

     ```
     keytool -import -alias myOldCertificateNickname -file myOldCertificate.crt -keystore myNewKeystore.jks
     ```
   - Start Glassfish

***Now this is most important!!*** 
For all this to work you need to know the password for both keystore's and the certifcates as well! And the MasterPW of Glassfish too!
Because Glassfish insist that all 3 Passwords have to be the same (MasterPW, Keystore Password, Password for the certificate)

And here a really good online guide for Installation of certificate in Glassfish

https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-glassfish/